Economics, business via the web, business, instantiating, resource allocation, on the web
I am looking for a web application, where, someone has your money, and, manages it/helps you manage it, on your behalf.
You have business ideas, that, may involve, social devotion of people to who you care about, or, manual tasks, or software, development, in offices, or anything really.
Any form of business.
The web application allows you, to:
digitally

Set up businesses
Delegate tasks
Monitor revenue curves
Make loans

Hello
Is it possible to develop a business application in this manner?
Thanks.
